# What package do I need to install to get PDF support in the Lyx document processor?

Tags: linux-mint, pdf, mate-desktop, lyx

I don't have PDF preview or export options available in Lyx. I'm using Linux Mint 17.3, with Mate. What package do I need to install to get the `export as pdf` option in Lyx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export as PDF, LyX uses `pdflatex`, which is in the `texlive-latex-base` package. Installing that and re-configuring LyX should enable the option.

Answer (score 0):

You must install texlive-lang-italy.
Replace "italy" with your language.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Could you explain why the language-specific TeXLive packages are necessary to enable PDF support in LyX?